# Is it wrong to remove outliers from dependent variable when adjusting a model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, outliers, poisson-regression

I'm beginning to study Generalized Linear Models and I was trying to adjust a model to the dataset [NMES1988](https://rdrr.io/cran/AER/man/NMES1988.html). More specifically, my goal is to adjust a Poisson Regression to this dataset considering visits as the dependent variable. At first, I fitted a Poisson Regression model considering certain covariates and got this residual plot:

[image]

Since it doesn't seem to show constant spread I decided to remove the outliers from my dependent variable (using the boxplot function) and adjusted a new Poisson model using the same covariates and got a residual plot with a much better appearance:

[image]

Is it ok to do something like this?

Comment: It depends. What is the nature of the outliers? Are they mistakes or just extreme values? What is the inferential objective of your study? Do the outliers contain useful or potentially useful information? In any case, your report should include full detail of the outliers and the rationale for their omission. Usually getting a better fit is not a good rationale.

Comment: You don't expect homoscedastic residuals with Poisson regression, even ideally. That's much of the point  of using it in the first place. Poisson regression usually goes with a logarithmic link (it can be defined that way, even) which usually takes care of outliers. As always outliers may sometimes be data points that are substantively rong, but more commonly with Poisson regression outliers are par for the course.

Comment: Removing outliers based on the data alone (including boxplots) will invalidate standard theory, which does not take into account that the dataset to be analysed has somehow been modified in a data dependent way. The only good reason for doing this is if there is information that these values are in fact wrong, or maybe strikingly unrealistic taken into account the meaning of the data. The baseline is that you really only want to discard observations that are misleading because measurements are wrong. The boxplot will not tell you this.

Comment: Note further that your plot is constrained by the fact that residuals for outcomes 0, 1, 2, etc. lie on curves and regions of the plot are unattainable. Bare residual versus fitted plots are not always helpful with generalized linear models that aren't plain regressions.

Comment: Medical events and expenditures are notorious for having long tails and outliers. The NMES reflects this phenomenon of our society. Many surveys that measure money items already have outliers trimmed back or removed. This is done to preserve confidentiality of the respondents. Read the documentation thoroughly, particularly the bits about measurement and variable processing to see what has already been done.

Comment: If these are Pearson residuals, Plot 1 is clearly overdispersed, plot 2 probably as well. The shape of the residuals is normal for a Poisson. Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poisson regression has constant variance by design since the conditional Poisson variance is equal to the conditional Poisson mean. So there is no reason to try to correct that problem. You might have outliers that are evidence of extra-Poisson variation, but those are much better handled by using alternative models such as negative binomial or zero-inflated, rather than by removing outliers.

By removing legitimate outliers, you lose valuable information concerning the nature of your $Y$ data.

Comment: I agree with where this ends, but the first sentence could be better phrased. As variance is equal to the mean it follows that a Poisson response has a variance that scales as the mean. In fact there is both analytical reasoning and experience that Poisson regression can work very well even if the conditional distribution isn't quite right or ideal.  What's really important is how far $\exp(Xb)$ captures the functional form.

Comment: Inserted "conditional" to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it all depends, on the aim of modeling. If your main aim is to estimate properly design statistic model, then removing outliers that are not results of error, or differ significantly may results in estimation of coefficient which differs significantly from real ones. In such case you should choose different modeling method as @BigBendRegion suggested.

However, if your aim is only to achive best predictive power of the model on out of sample date, removing outliers may help with that.

Comment: This is cryptic without much detail. If outliers are genuine, it would seem that omitting them could hardly make a model more useful for the future. Consider floods, fires and what not.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.